# Use the k3s and ctr commands to import the image, but the image cannot be found by using crictl

Tags: go, kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I am using ctr commands to import the image `ctr -n k8s.io images import alpine-3.15.tar --platform linux/amd64`
and I am using crictl to view the images `crictl images`
[image]
My question is why there is no alpine image?
If I run ctr view images `ctr -n k8s.io images ls`
[image]
Why can I find it by specifying the namespace with ctr?
But when I execute the same command on the slave node, I got the correct result. Why is this ?
[image]

How can I make the result of the master node the same as that of the slave node ?